# overloaded array subscript [] operator slow

Tags: c++, performance, operator-overloading

I have written my own Array class in c++ and overloaded the array subscript [] operator, code:

```
inline dtype &operator[](const size_t i) { return _data[i]; }
inline dtype operator[](const size_t i) const { return _data[i];}
```

where _data is a pointer to the memory block containing the array. Profiling shows that this overloaded operator alone is taking about 10% of the overall computation time (on a long monte carlo simulation, and I am compiling using g++ with maximum optimization). This seems a lot, any idea why this is?

edited: dtype is a double, and _data is a pointer to an array of double

Comment: What is `dtype`, and what is `_data`?

Comment: It's important to note that the second `operator []` returns a copy of `dtype`. If `dtype` has an expensive copy it might be why it shows up in the profiler. Also because you did not make the operator `const` at the end of the operator the compiler will have a harder time optimizing the [] calls.

Comment: Try to return const dtype& on the second case, it will return const reference and allows to avoid expensive full copy.

Comment: dtype is a double, and _data is a pointer to an array of double (edited question)

Comment: Maybe cache misses are the culprit?  In that case, there might not be much you can do.

Comment: @aschepler: How does that make any sense? If cache misses were the problem, it would be slow in both cases.

Comment: @Dudeson Sorry, what are the two cases?

Comment: @aschepler: I meant the two cases `access through _data` and `access through operator[]`.

Answer (score 2):

The `const` overload of `operator[]` is actually returning a copy instead of a `dtype const &`. If dtype is big, the copy might be expensive.

Prototyping it like that should solve that problem :

```
inline dtype const & operator[] (const size_t i) const { return _data[i]; }
```

Comment: Or the extra level of indirection might make it worse. We can't tell whether that's an issue without knowing what `dtype` is.