# Operator () is time consuming (profiling in C++)

Tags: c++, profiling, montecarlo

I have a user defined 2D array stored in a contiguous block of memory and thus overloaded the () operator.

```
void CheckIndex(int& i, int& j) const //checks for index out of bounds error 
{
  if ( i < -nghost || i >= cols_x+nghost ||
       j < -nghost || j >= rows_y+nghost )
    {
      std::cout << "Index out of bounds. Exiting."
        << std::endl;
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

double& operator()(int i, int j) const
{
  CheckIndex(i,j);
  int jump = cols_x + 2*nghost;
  return mesh[ (i+nghost) + (j+nghost)*jump ];
}
double& operator()(int i, int j); //implementation same as above
```

I use my class in Monte Carlo simulations. After profiling I see that 15% of the time is spent in `CheckIndex` (which is called every time the `operator()` is called) and another 15% in `operator()(int i,int j) const` itself.

There is a similar issue here [overloaded array subscript [] operator slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864368/overloaded-array-subscript-operator-slow)
but I can't say that it helped since my overloaded operators return references and copying is avoided.

I tried to inline those functions but I am getting linker errors. However, I have also seen that most probably the compiler (g++) does this by itself.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: the reason for `operator()` being slow is most likely in the code.

Comment: the issue with `CheckIndices` is probably simple to solve: Don't check indices on each access. For example in a tight loop `for (int i=0;i < size; ++i) x(i);` checking indices on each iteration is a waste. Make it the callers responsibility to make sure the indices are right

Comment: I edited with the implementation of ```operator()```

Comment: also note that `15%` might be just because `15%` of your workload is actually accessing elements. In that case the `15%` is not a problem per se, though still a good candidate to improve overall performance

Comment: now the implementation of `CheckIndices` is missing, and a typical use-case. Where are the 15% coming from? Please read about [mcve]

Comment: ot: Do you really return a non-const reference from the `const` method? Is `mesh` mutable?

Comment: No mesh is not ```mutable```. I don't know how to answer your first question. Do you mean that dependnding on the code maybe I should return ```const double&``` ?

Comment: You should return just double. `double& operator()(int i, int j)` and `double operator()(int i, int j) const`

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Why should I do that?

Comment: because you don't want const operator to change data. That is standard issue - decalre two operator for const and non-const object, const operator would guarantee data immutability

Answer (score 2):

Bounds checking is well-known to be slow. Early CPU's even had a special function for it, so much of a performance impact does it cause. Even today, C++ defines `std::vector::at` to do bounds checking, and leaves the ordinary `vector::operator[]` unchecked.

This makes sense. Most of the critical use of `operator[]` is in loops, and there you only need to check the loop boundaries. The whole middle of the loop is safe.

C++ has further ways to make loops safe. Idioms like `for (element:collection)` don't force you to write the bounds, so you can't get it wrong either.

As a minor optimization, C++20 allows

```
  if ( i < -nghost || i >= cols_x+nghost ||
       j < -nghost || j >= rows_y+nghost )
    {
      [[unlikely]]
      std::cout << "Index out of bounds. Exiting.\n";
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Comment: So a solution can be to check the smallest and largest values that ```()``` can assume before entering the loop.

Comment: @Angelos if you use eg iterators, there is not really the need to check, because it is hard to get it wrong, you just use `begin` and `end`. WIth the range based for loop you dont even have a chance to mistype `being` or `end` because its all hidden

Comment: But how can I use iterators when my array is implemented by a raw pointer ```double*```? And I am not sure if I can avoid this because I need to use the FFTW3 library.

Comment: @Angelos: What you need for FFTW3 is a contiguous memory allocation. A `new double[]` is contiguous, but so is a `std::vector<double>`. The latter is more safe. Still, you will need to pass valid bounds to FFTW3, or **it** will access unallocated memory. That shows the general pattern: be careful with the bounds; then individual element accesses will be safe.

Comment: If I change to ```std::vector<double>``` then I should delete the Rule of 5 that I have implemented right? No need for destructors etc?

Comment: @Angelos: That's quite likely. It's sometimes said that the "Rule of 0" is better than the "Rule of 5". The Rule of 5 applies to classes that manage a resource, but especially memory is best managed by somebody else (such as the compiler writes who wrote `std::vector` for you).